# Log stdout of spawned process and only spawned process of Expect

Tags: expect

I am so sorry but I am really confused as to how stdout and logging works on Expect.

Actually I just want to log the stdout of a spawned process of Expect to a file.

With an easy command like:

```
echo hello
```

Stdout is:

```
hello
```

So I was just testing this with Expect:

```
$ expect
expect1.1> log_file log.txt
expect1.2> spawn echo hello
spawn echo hello
1978
expect1.3>
```

But in log.txt I got:

```
expect1.2> spawn echo hellospawn echo hello
1978
expect1.3>
```

How do I get expect to log just the stdout from the spawned process? In this case it is just:

```
hello
```

Comment: this is kind of impossible with `log_file`. you can manually extract the data you are interested in and save it to file.

Comment: hmm @sexpect, but it doesn't even log the pure output from the spawned process, even if intermingled with the output from Expect? see the above example. there's not a "hello" that belongs to "echo hello" and not Expect?